# Encender y apagar flash de cámara en android studio

Tags: android-studio, cámara, widget

Estoy haciendo un widget para encender y apagar el flash de la cámara. Logro que encienda el el flash, pero cuando lo apago me da el siguiente error:
"Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference"
Adjunto el código implementado para la revisión

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
    if (intent.getAction().equals("encender")){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M ){
                try {
                    cameraManager = (CameraManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
                    if (cameraManager != null) {
                        cameraId = cameraManager.getCameraIdList()[0];
                        cameraManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, true);
                        Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "Encendido", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    }
    else {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("apagar")){
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                try {
                    cameraManager = (CameraManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
                    if (cameraManager != null) {
                        cameraId = cameraManager.getCameraIdList()[0];
                        cameraManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, false);
                        Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "Apagado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿De que forma llamas a esos eventos?, agrega el código que lo realiza por favor.

Comment: Ya solucione el problema, no puse mas código por que la pagina no me dejaba. Borro la pregunta o la doy por solucionada?